# Should an array be declared before using it?

Tags: php, variables

Which one is better practice, code A or B:

A:

```
    $array = array();
    $array[] = 'value';
```

B ( use the array without declaring it an array ):

```
    $array[] = 'value'
```

Comment: either's fine. but if $array was use for something OTHER than an array previously, you'll have trouble .e.g `$x = 'hello'; $x[] = 'there';` is going to barf on you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best Practice is declaring it.

Reason: if for some reason someone turned on register_globals and $array is set before you use it, you can end up with strange results.
If you declare it, you are always sure you have an empty array.

Comment: thanks, simple and understandable answer.

Answer (score 2):

`A` is better.  <del>`B` will result in a PHP `Notice` when run, but will still work the same.</del>  As some other people mentioned and I overlooked initially, `A` will also make your code more robust by making sure that `$array` is what you want it to be when you need it and not some other variable type or previously defined variable.

Edit: the one time PHP doesn't throw a notice when using an undefined variable is when appending to an uninitialized array.  From php.net:

> E_NOTICE level error is issued in case of working with uninitialized variables, however not in the case of appending elements to the uninitialized array.

Comment: Are you sure about the PHP notice? I've never seen it in this case, and I do have notices enabled. Nevertheless, declaring `array()` is definitively a better practice.

Comment: Never seen a notice when assigning array values without declaring array...

Answer (score 2):

or 
C: $array = array('value');

Answer (score 2):

A is the better way but if its a known value I would do 
    $array=array('value');

[try this site](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php6p2.html)

Answer (score 0):

IMO it depends on the complexity of your script. Just as it is with for example $i in foreach loops you might use array's a lot.

By defining the array first, you make sure that it is a new and empty array, which ensures that it contains no data from previous usage.

Answer (score 0):

`A` Is better than `B` as @G-Nugget has said for the same reasons but the corollary is that it also makes your code harder to read if you have variables popping up out of nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), the part mentioning **Creating/modifying with square bracket syntax**, actually implies that creating arrays with `$array[] = 'value';` is equally as right as creating arrays by declaring the variable as such before assigning values to it.

In other words, don't worry about it.