# Define Array before populating it?

Tags: php, arrays

should I define array first and then populate it? Or is array definition totally unnecessary?

```
$a = [];
$a['key1'] = 33;
$a['key2'] = 12;
```

Comment: Learn basics. You can initiate array with values `$a = ['key1' => 33, 'key2' => 12]`

Comment: I know, that's why I'm asking. Just reviewing code.. Should I complain about this thing

Comment: This question is actually useful for PHP beginners.

Comment: You could also just `$a['key1'] = 33; $a['key2'] = 12;`

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should an array be declared before using it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14901793/should-an-array-be-declared-before-using-it)

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to define your variable as an array first, PHP recognizes that as an array when you behave like an array with that first time.

however, maybe if you define your variables first is good for writing a clean code.

Comment: This would serve better as a comment to the question. We'd like answers such as this to be a bit more extensive and backed by links to language documentation or spec for example.

Answer (score 0):

[Per the PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying) it's not necessary to define the variable as an array before using square brackets to assign values to it.

> If `$arr` doesn't exist yet or is set to null or false, it will be created, so this is also an alternative way to create an array

Therefore, this syntax is perfectly valid for creating a new array:

```php
// assume $arr has not been declared
$arr[] = 'Some value';
$arr[$key] = 'Some other value';
```

However, in that same section, the PHP manual also cautions against this practice.

> This practice is however discouraged because if `$arr` already contains some value (e.g. string from request variable) then this value will stay in the place and `[]` may actually stand for [string access operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr). It is always better to initialize a variable by a direct assignment.

Source:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying

Comment: Before posting a new answer, read the comments under the question to see if any duplication nominations have been made.  If a pre-existing question represents the same question, please vote to close instead of adding an answer.  If you have something to add to an older answer, please post your advice there. If the older question is closed, then you should fight for it to be reopened or resign to the fact that not all questions are on-topic on Stack Overflow. https://imgur.com/a/s0f0btO